# Can any program of C be written in R programming language?

Tags: c, r

I want to know whether any program which is written using C programming language can be written using R programming language or not. I know that it is possible to call C code from R, but I want to know if I want to write every algorithm in R from scratch whether it is possible or not.

I want to know does R has all constructs required to implement all programs written in C lanuage?

Comment: How this question is opinion based?

Comment: I guess it depends on the community. If you ask this question in "Computer Science" it is obvious. If you ask practical coders here, you can of cause create a debate. So it may be in the wrong community. But since the questioner wanted to start "from scratch", it seems to be a more fundamental and thus theoretical question.

Comment: This depends on how you define the "C programming language."  If you mean standard C, the answer is yes, but few programs are actually written in standard C.  Most will use platform-specific libraries, and this is where you will not be able to do a translation.  So the answer is "yes" or it is "no," but neither answer really seems to satisfy the inherent meaning in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both are [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).